# How to Validate JSON with Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson JSON take a string and determine if it is valid JSON.  Can anyone suggest a code sample to use (Java)?

Comment: How do you defina that JSON is valid?

Comment: @Slavus: Any string satisfying JSON syntax standard is a valid JSON. We do not define a valid JSON.

Comment: I'm years late and this may not have been available in 2012, but are you thinking of [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not sure what your use case for this is, but this should do it:

```
public boolean isValidJSON(final String json) {
   boolean valid = false;
   try {
      final JsonParser parser = new ObjectMapper().getJsonFactory()
            .createJsonParser(json);
      while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
      }
      valid = true;
   } catch (JsonParseException jpe) {
      jpe.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
   }

   return valid;
}
```

Comment: getJsonFactory() is deprecated.

Comment: Short and elegant solution is available here [Thanks to @pdem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29414638/452708)
`try{

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...;
  JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(yourJsonString);

} catch(JsonProcessingException e){........}`

Comment: both methods depreciated: getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(json).
Use this istead: getFactory().createParser(json)

Comment: Im confused cause I learned in my informatics study that "Exceptions should be used for exceptional conditions; things you don't expect to happen."... Validating input isn't very exceptional. But of course I understand, that this is a useful solution

Comment: just use .getFactory() instead of .getJsonFactory()

Comment: new ObjectMapper().getJsonFactory()
            .createJsonParser(json); is deprecated

Comment: Hi. I scan code with Forify. It warn me Json Inject with ObjectMpper.read. I have tried with the above solution. But It cannot fix the problem.

Comment: What is the value of declaring the input parameter as `final String json`?

Answer (score 25):

Although Perception's answer probably will fit many needs, there are some problems it won't catch, one of them is duplicate keys, consider the following example:

```java
String json = "{ \"foo\" : \"bar\", \"foo\" : \"baz\" }";
```

As a complement, you can check for duplicate keys with the following code:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY);
objectMapper.readTree(json);
```

It throws `JsonProcessingException` on duplicate key or other error.

Answer (score 15):

With Jackson I use this function:

```
public static boolean isValidJSON(final String json) throws IOException {
    boolean valid = true;
    try{ 
        objectMapper.readTree(json);
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: @mc20 I have run `System.out.println(isValidJSON("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"));` and it is working fine returning me `true`. Please try again.

Comment: `isValidJSON("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}foo"` would fail it. Having extra stuff after the valid JSON. Added this             mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS); to catch it.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you meant.

Comment: EOP - Exception-oriented programming. It isn't a good pattern.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using [Bean Validation API](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) separately: that is, first bind data to a POJO, then validate POJO. Data format level Schemas are in my opinion not very useful: one usually still has to validate higher level concerns, and schema languages themselves are clumsy, esp. ones that use format being validated (XML Schema and JSON Schema both have this basic flaw).
Doing this makes code more modular, reusable, and separates concerns (serialization, data validation).

But I would actually go one step further, and suggest you have a look at [DropWizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) -- it integrates Jackson and Validation API implementation (from Hibernate project).

Comment: Dropwizard seems to have moved on to a new home (www.dropwizard.io) and calls itself now "a Java framework for developing ops-friendly, high-performance, RESTful web services". Haven't read on but it possibly still integrates Jackson and Validation API. Not sure if you need all the rest.

Comment: Yes, DropWizard still integrates Jackson and Validation API as of now (feb 2016). I don't see those changing for the project, it is quite mature at this point. You can of course use other binding libraries (JAX-RS is highly pluggable), but as the baseline those 2 libs will probably remain.

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean isValidJson(String json) {
    try {
        objectMapper.readTree(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using java.util.Optional in Java 8. This allows to return an object and to use in the calling code a more functional approach.

This is another possible implementation:

```
public Optional<JsonProcessingException> validateJson(final String json) {
    try{ 
        objectMapper.readTree(json);
        return Optional.empty();
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        return Optional.of(e);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method like this:

```
jsonHelper.validateJson(mappingData.getMetadataJson())
                    .map(e -> String.format("Error: %s at %s", e.getMessage(), e.getLocation().toString()))
                    .orElse("Valid JSON");
```

Answer (score 1):

Inproving the other answers

```
public static boolean isValidJSON(final String json) throws IOException {
    boolean valid = true;
    try{ 
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY);
        objectMapper.readTree(json);
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I think there is a typo for `objectMapper.readTree(json);`, it is supposed to be `mapper.readTree(json);`.