# Jackson decodes "14:89:FD:D3:E7:8C" to 14

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following piece of code which decodes "14:89:FD:D3:E7:8C" to 14 while it should return some kind of error:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree("14:89:FD:D3:E7:8C");
String str = node.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

Why is it so? Can I make jackson to return errors on incorrect json strings?

Comment: Which version? Some aspects of parsing of root-level values have been changed with later versions, to disallow parsing values like yours.

Comment: @StaxMan I am using some older version but I can switch to newest Jackson-2.6.1 if there is some good solution.

Comment: mostly just wondering if this particular problem might have been solved already, so quickly test to see if behavior is still the same. Latest is 2.6.3, but in this regard 2.6.1 should work the same. As to the original problem, you would get an exception if you tried to parse more entries from the stream, but since `readTree()` only reads a single root-level value, "14" fulfills that obligation; `JsonParser` will not try to advance past valid token.

Comment: Actually, I can not reproduce this problem with Jackson 2.6: I get an exception complaining about ':' not being valid separator.

Comment: @StaxMan I was convienced I have checked with newer version and I failed same as with older version. Your post made me recheck that and you are right Jackson is throwing and exception. If you turn your comment in to answer I will accept it instead of currently accepted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think older versions did not use to do look-ahead to detect anomaly, but simple accept anything that looks like a number, stop decoding. Error would only be detected if trying to advance the stream (or possibly not even then for some cases).

Newer versions should detect this by forcing whitespace to be found, or end-of-input; and if not found indicate an error. I verified this with 2.6.3, but I think fix went in somewhere around 2.4 or so.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to validate if your input is a valid JSON string first - [How to Validate JSON with Jackson JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226897/how-to-validate-json-with-jackson-json)