# best practice to validate if JSON string generated via java is valid (structure & data validation)

Tags: java, json, validation, jackson

I am generating JSON string via java jackson and write to a file. 
Before writing to a file, I want to validate if the generated JSON is valid with respect to structure(not null values for mandatory fields) and the data is valid (for ex, 'gender' has either 'male' or 'female' values only).

I researched in google and found that JSON Schema validation is doable. But i want to know what is the recommended best practice for my requirement.

Comment: Best practice is a manner of opinion. You can search for json-schema spec (currently version 4 - http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) implementation and you will get a lot of libraries. Frameworks like Spring and Jersey implemented annotations to validate Jackson field like @NotNull, etc. It depends what you are using now etc.

Comment: This might be a relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226897/how-to-validate-json-with-jackson-json

Comment: Thanks shikloshi and ystark. json schema version 4 looks good.