# Jackson parser not failing with JsonParseException for obviously bad json

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm looking into why a simple Jackson JSON deserialisation setup is not failing on my clearly broken Json. In my application I MUST confirm that the input is valid json before doing mapping to Java type.

```java
final String json = "[\"plop\"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]";

final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

final JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory();

jf.setCodec(om);

final JsonParser jp = jf.createParser(json);

jp.disable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA);

jp.readValueAsTree()
```

(I run this in IntelliJ Evaluate )

You see my JSON has however many dangling array close ] as I choose. The parser doesn't care about them.

Other rubbish that this setup appears to allow are:

```java
final String json = "{}]]]]";
final String json = "[{},[]]]]]]]]";
final String json = "[{},{}]}}}}";
```

You see, the problem is not confined to dangling ] either - same issue for }.

I wonder if the parser stops looking for stuff after the final thing to be "expected" is seen - rather than consuming all the input.

Any ideas, anyone? Bueller?

Rich

Answer (score 1):

You are right. After deserializing array (in case of `"["blah"]]]"` it stops and doesn't read anything else, so you can put anything after closing `]`.

See `ObjectMapper.readTree` for details.

```
@Override
public <T extends TreeNode> T readTree(JsonParser p)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    /* 02-Mar-2009, tatu: One twist; deserialization provider
     *   will map JSON null straight into Java null. But what
     *   we want to return is the "null node" instead.
     */
    /* 05-Aug-2011, tatu: Also, must check for EOF here before
     *   calling readValue(), since that'll choke on it otherwise
     */
    DeserializationConfig cfg = getDeserializationConfig();
    JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();
    if (t == null) {
        t = p.nextToken();
        if (t == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    JsonNode n = (JsonNode) _readValue(cfg, p, JSON_NODE_TYPE);
    if (n == null) {
        n = getNodeFactory().nullNode();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T result = (T) n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It's a bit crap as a parser, isn't it?. If you put my jsons into any free "json validator" website that Google gives, they all pit it out as invalid. But not jackson. I'm looking for but not found yet any test suites for erroneous json.

Comment: It does it this way because you may want to process rest of you input yourself. If you want to make sure that all input is consumed, just check `jp` state with `jp.readValueAsTree()` if it return `null` everything is fine, if it return something or throw exception then input is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the usage advice. I've lost a bit of confidence with jackson - on first use Gson will emit a parse issue if something doesn't parse. It's just simpler.

I need to separate parse issues from deserialisation issues, and I don't (from my fiddling yesterday) feel that the two processes are separate in jackson.

Comment: Enabling `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS` catches such cases with Jackson. Also see comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36713138/117750